# Git vim editor config

Tags: windows, git, vim, editor, commit-message

I work in windows and I use vim like default editor for commit.
I would like configure vim to save the commit with Windows file format (CRLF)

How I can do?
Where is the vim configurations for git?

Comment: vim has its own tag, [tag:vim], and even its own (currently still beta-test) stackexchange site, https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, thanks I don't know that exists, anyway I think this is a question related git. I use vim for other purpose and works like I want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git commit message plugin is `~/.vim/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`. Set this:

```
setlocal fileformat=dos
```

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27fileformat%27